# Update Linux config files when a user applies changes from a front-end

Tags: database, architecture, system

First of all, I am a system guy and not a developer at all. So, my sincere apologies if anything is unclear or even dumb.

I have configured a cloud network service on a VPS and it works. It is based on Linux classic packages and the configuration is made through system .config files. I'll refer it later as the back-end.

Now,  would like to offer the possibility to customize the back-end configuration through a web front-end. I didn't begin to code it but I'll do it in react (with a mysql or pgsql db).

When a client modifies something on his panel/front-end, the change(s) must be propagated to the back-end config files.

To do so, I was thinking about :

1. **From the back-end** : watching db events and update the files in
   consequence (my current preference)
2. **From the DB** : using stored procedure to call a web service or
   something that will update the back-end files.
3. **From the front-end** : calling a rest api to update the back-end file. (I am not in favor of this cause it should be synchronous and I would have to keep a trace of the changes. So I think it's best using a DB)

What do you think about these solutions ? Are there any other better solutions (I guess there are) ?

For the moment, all of these (front, back, db) would be on the same server but for security and design purposes, they won't be in the foreseeable future (at least, the back-end and the db won't be).

Thank you very much for your help cause I'm kinda lost.

Best regards,

Alakyl

Edit : Title

Answer (score 1):

I like your thinking style when you say "You are not in favour of synchronous style".
I also like your futuristic thinking that the some of these systems wont be on the same server which means it will be distributed.

The answer to this lies in your problem explanation itself.
We can simplify this solution of yours, post which you don't need DB component.

The solution is to use an asynchronous style of invoking the service from the front end.

1. Front-end will generate a message (containing the service name to be invoked and also the input - which is nothing but the config key name and the config value to be stored for it).
2. This message is sent to a message infrastructure (which persists the message for a specific duration of time). This avoids storing in DB and also writing Store Procedures to invoke the webservice. Also if DB is present, this again becomes synchronous style where Front-end doesnt work if DB is down and hence the new values are lost and not saved to config files.
3. Receiver polls the message infrastructure for any new messages, and invokes the corresponding service(implemented using REST or gRPC) with the correct parameters.
4. The associated service gets invoked and it stores the new config values in the config file.